# Signals Keyboard Movement AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, signals

I'm trying to get my keyboard movement to work using signals and a `Hero` class. So far I can get the signal to dispatch but I can't get it to take the keyboard input. Should I be using signals for movement at all or should I just call the function from the `Hero` class.

This is the code for Hero:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import org.osflash.signals.Signal;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.natejc.input.KeyboardManager;
import com.natejc.input.KeyCode;
/**
 * ...
 * @author Kevin Raskell
 */
public class Hero extends MovieClip
{
    public var defeatedSignal :Signal = new Signal();
    public var _nHeroMovement :Number = 5;
    public var moveSignal :Signal;


    public function Hero() 
    {
        super();
        this.mouseChildren = false;
        this.mouseEnabled = false;

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, heroMovement);

        moveSignal = new Signal();

    }

    public function heroDefeated()
    {
        trace("You have died");
    }

    public function heroMovement($e:Event):void
    {
        moveSignal.dispatch();
        if (this)
        {               
            if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.DOWN))
            {
                if (this.y + this.height > this.stage.stageHeight || this.y - this.height <= 0)
                {
                    this.y += -15;
                    this.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.y += _nHeroMovement;
                this.gotoAndPlay("Down");
            }
            else if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.UP))
            {
                if (this.y + this.height > this.stage.stageHeight || this.y - this.height <= 0)
                {
                    this.y += 15;
                    this.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.y -= _nHeroMovement;
                this.gotoAndPlay("Up");
            }

            if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.LEFT))
            {
                if (this.x + this.width > this.stage.stageWidth || this.x - this.width <= 0) 
                {
                    this.x += 15;
                    this.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }                   
                this.x -= _nHeroMovement;
                this.gotoAndPlay("Left");

            }
            else if (KeyboardManager.instance.isKeyDown(KeyCode.RIGHT))
            {   
                if (this.x + this.width > this.stage.stageWidth || this.x - this.width <= 0) 
                {
                    this.x += -15;
                    this.gotoAndPlay("Idle");
                    return;
                }
                this.x += _nHeroMovement;
                this.gotoAndPlay("Right");
            }
        }//end if
    }//end heroMovement     
}//end Hero
}//end package
```

This is in the main function:

```
this.mcHero.moveSignal.add(moveHero);

    }

    private function moveHero():void
    {
        trace("Testing" + count);
        count++;
    }
```

The counting was for testing purposes for myself to see what was happening.

Comment: Is one of the `isKeyDown` checks ever passing? Does it ever gets inside any of those? As the problem seems to be with that KeyboardManager, which is not shown here. The signal system doesn't matter as it's working. It's up to you to decide how to structure your code - you may or may not use it. But the problem is to catch if keyboard is pressed.

Comment: no the keydown isn't passing. it seems like it isn't actually getting into the function. i'm not sure how i go about catching the keyboard interaction. the keyboardmanager is something that our teacher gave us

Comment: solved the issue, i forgot to use `KeyboardManager.init(this.stage);` in the main ugh. been hitting my head against the wall for like 2 days with this!