# keyboard input from separate classes for movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, keyboard-events, keyboard-input

I was wondering how you get keyboard input from a separate class in as3. I have a class that will use the arrow keys to move but it needs to be in the `hero` class how do i call the movement function from the main function?

Answer (score 0):

You will normally listen for keyboard events from the stage, so the best way to handle this would probably be to just add the specific keyboard logic you need to your Hero class itself.

You can listen for the ADDED_TO_STAGE and REMOVED_FROM_STAGE events in your Hero to trigger when to add and remove the keyboard event listeners.

A basic example might work like this:

```
public class Hero extends Sprite
{

    // Constructor
    public function Hero()
    {
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
    }


    // Event handlers

    protected function onAddedToStage( event:Event ):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
        this.addEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemovedFromStage );
        this.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
        this.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp );
    }

    protected function onRemovedToStage( event:Event ):void
    {
        this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
        this.removeEventListener( Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemovedFromStage );
        this.stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown );
        this.stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp );
    }

    protected function onKeyDown( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        switch (event.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                // Start movement
                break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                // Start movement
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function onKeyUp( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {
        switch (event.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                // Stop movement
                break;
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                // Stop movement
                break;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a heroMovement function already made:
This is a post that I previously did that explains everything
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233098/signals-keyboard-movement-as3?noredirect=1#comment35555366_23233098`